# Как изменить оси (X, Y) на графике в модуле matplotlib python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, статистика, графики

Иммется код, который генерирует график. Это соотношения ТОП1-10, и количество просмотров за которым они и сортировались в этот ТОП.

Какие данные на входе:

(Значения Y оси идут реверсно(с меньшего до большего, потому-что доставал их через .pop())

```
x = ['Top10', 'Top9', 'Top8', 'Top7', 'Top6', 'Top5', 'Top4', 'Top3', 'Top2', 'Top1']
y = [257034, 260972, 343206, 362693, 413886, 521024, 670460, 722834, 748542, 1217913]
```

После выполнения `plt.bar(x.pop(), y.pop())`(10 раз), получаю следующий график:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить отображения Y оси?
Что за ошибка появилась 1е6 ?

Какие будут варианты решения?

P.S. Возможно ли сделать на Y оси отображения только тех чисел, которые я задаю при создание графика? То есть: 1217913, 748542 ...

**UPDATE!!!**
Ответ от пользователя *handowl*

> Можно использовать pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'positions':x, 'values':y})

ax = df.plot.bar(x='positions', y='values', rot=30)
#ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])
#ax.get_legend().remove()

plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')

plt.show()
```

После выполнения вашего кода я получаю сделующий результат:

[image: Результат]

1. Почему-то стали открываться 2 окна.
2. Что это за синие продолжения на графике после ТОП5 и до ТОП1?

Код функции построения графика полностью:

https://pastebin.com/Z3JEENpW

Comment: С такими данными вам реально надо на Pandas сразу переходить, а не мучиться со словарями

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'positions':x, 'values':y})

ax = df.plot.bar(x='positions', y='values', rot=30)
#ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])
#ax.get_legend().remove()

plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')

plt.show()
```

Кстати, зачем Вы попите? Можно вот так:

```
sorted_values = sorted(zip(x, y), key=lambda e: e[1], reverse=True)
x = [pair[0] for pair in sorted_values]
y = [pair[1] for pair in sorted_values]
```

или вот так:

```
x = x[::-1]
y.sort(reverse=True)
```

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста, я сделал update в вопросе.

Comment: @VitaliiShchudlo а есть полный код? или вы просто запускаете этот?

Comment: Да, обновил.

Там просто ещё обработка тех данных что мне приходят. Но я постарался в комментарии все вписать.

Comment: Сможете что-то подсказать?

Comment: @VitaliiShchudlo финт с двумя окнами у меня не удалось повторить, но два графика на одном холсте - это оттого, что вы делаете `ax = df.plot.bar(...)`, а потом второй раз создаете бары попами в цикле: `plt.bar(...)`. Может быть(!), окно появляется из-за этого же.

Comment: Если убрать мой цикл, то да, создает нормально график. Только уже всё одного цвета, соотвественно plt.legend уже не получается сделать, а то не понятно какое видео на каком месте...
Ладно

Comment: @VitaliiShchudlo можно убрать строку, где строится через pandas. Или можно добавить параметр `colors=[...]`

Comment: Я уже нашёл ответ. Добавил в конце перед plt.grid() следующую строку: plt.gca().ticklabel_format(axis = 'y', style='plain'). И всё заработало

Answer (score 2):

Всё можно сделать, но в таком варианте как вы хотите цифры будут наезжать друг на друга:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x = ['Top10', 'Top9', 'Top8', 'Top7', 'Top6', 'Top5', 'Top4', 'Top3', 'Top2', 'Top1']
y = [257034, 260972, 343206, 362693, 413886, 521024, 670460, 722834, 748542, 1217913]

x1 = x.copy()
y1 = y.copy()
for i in range(10):
    plt.bar(x1.pop(), y1.pop());

plt.yticks(y); # выставляем только нужные нам метки на оси y
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y') # форматирование меток
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]